# Building pjsua python on Windows

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-2012, pjsip

I am trying to build the _pjsua C extension in windows, using Visual studio 2012.

I downloaded the source code from here - http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm.

I have Python27 installed, and have added the **C:\Python27\include** and the **C:\Python27\libs** directories to the project **include** and **library** directories.

I followed the instructions here - https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Build_Install.

In the **Microsoft Windows with Visual Studio** under **Step 1: Building the C Extension** its says:

```
Visual Studio 2005:

1. Open pjproject-vs8.sln from the PJSIP distribution directory.

2. Select either Debug or Release from the build configuration
Note: the Python module does not support other build configurations.

3. In Visual Studio, right click python_pjsua project from the Solution Explorer panel, and select Build from the pop-up menu.
Note: the python_pjsua project is not built by default if you build the solution, hence it needs to be built manually by right-clicking and select Build from the pop-up menu.

4. The _pjsua.pyd Python module will be placed in pjsip-apps\lib directory.
or in case of debug, it will be _pjsua_d.pyd
```

In step 3 (building the python_pjsua project) I get error

```
pjsua error lnk1181 cannot open input file python24.lib
```

in the **C:/Python27/libs** I have file **python27.lib**.

Does this C extension works only with Python 2.4 (python24)??

thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing with same problem, and wondering if you managed to compile PJSUA for Python on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

No, it not so.
You can use simple hack:
**Copy python27.lib** and rename it **to python24.lib**, then place it to **C:/Python27/libs** folder. Now you can build you extension, then run in cmd **python setup-vc.py install** command.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution for this is:

1. Open python_pjsua property pages (righ click->Properties);
2. Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.
3. Change python24.lib to python27.lib (or python24_d.lib to python27_d.lib if debugging).

It should work and compile with no problem.